# System error 111 (connection refused) , Failed to connect

Tags: streaming, gstreamer, vmware, vlc, rtsp

I'm trying to stream video via RTSP in my ubuntu PC.
The video file to be streamed `big_buck_bunny_h264.mov` is located in following location of my PC :home/user/Downloads/

I'm using gstreamer to stream the video.
Below is the gstreamer command I'm trying :

> gst-launch-1.0 rtsprc
>   location=rtsp://127.0.0.1:9000/home/user/Downloads/big_buck_bunny_h264.mov
>   latency=0 ! decodebin ! autovideosink

But I'm getting following error on terminal:

> **System error 111 (connection refused) , Failed to connect**

Also I tried streaming via RTSP using **VLC** player . (open VLC -> Media -> Open Network Streaming -> Enter the url -> Play )
Im getting following error message:
Connection Failed, VLC could not connect to 127.0.0.1:9000. VLC is unable to open the URL.

**From the above 2 scenarios (Gstreamer and VLC) , I assume there is something issue with the networking/network interface.**

**The Current OS I'm using is guest OS Ubuntu 14.04. (I'm acessing ubuntu via VMware Player from windows PC). Network is bridged between windows and ubuntu.**

So is this the reason , why RTSP streaming is not working fine in my case ?
Is there any alternative ?
Also kindly tell me , whether I'm using the correct command and file path to stream the video via RTSP.
Do I need to setup LIVE555 streaming server to start streaming video at transmitter ?

Comment: You need a RTSP server which actually serves the file to be played. If you don't have that no client will be able to connect and receive the stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry but you have that all wrong..

To use rtspsrc does not mean you are streaming.. it means you are opening an existing stream(as client), as Florian mentioned you have to have running rtsp server which is serving the files to clients..

Clients can be - as you already tried - a vlc or gstreamer pipe with rtspsrc element, or some other players like mplayer(smplayer has also nice user interface for that imho) etc..

There are various options for rtsp servers: gstreamer rtsp server (mentioned [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtp.html) ), [crtmpserver](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/crtmpserver/), also vlc (but not the way you used it, check [this](http://blog.julien.org/2008/12/howto-setting-up-vod-server-with-vlc.html) ) and you will find more..

You can also read this [nice article](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169578&seqNum=3) about rt*p family of protocols.

Yes you can use live555 as rtsp server at Ubuntu VM and access it from your windows with vlc as you already tried..

Also keep in mind that you usualy do not use full system path (home/etc/etc) to access rtsp files but rather rtsp access point. That means dedicated folder which contains your media files you will access it for example like rtsp://192.168.1.123/vod/file.mp4 where vod is this access folder (or whatever it is called).

HTH

Comment: Thanks alot for explaining in detail.